# set NSWindow focused

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, focus, nswindow, nspanel

I have an app winth one window and one panel, attached to this window.

steps:

1. deactivate my app (app opened, but without the focus)
2. click on a button on panel (panel is focused now, but main window is not)

How to set focus to the main window (parent window) from the panel?

Comment: Is the main window a Cocoa main window? Is your application NSDocument-based? Do you mean key window status when you say focus?

Comment: When I say "to set focus", I mean "to activate" main window, set key window status. Application is always on top of the screen. And when I click somwhere outside the main window the application deactivating, but placed on top.

Comment: Your answer with activateWithOptions: worked for me too. If you post it as an answer I'd be happy to upvote it :)

Comment: Make sure your panel responds YES to canBecomeKeyWindow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by focus, and whether what you call main window is a main window as defined in Cocoa. Assuming it is a Cocoa main window and focus is the same as key status,

```
[[NSApp mainWindow] makeKeyWindow];
```

or

```
[[NSApp mainWindow] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

If it is not a Cocoa main window, you need to have a reference to it and send it `-makeKeyWindow` or `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:`.

Comment: its not working. Maybe, because main window is NSFloatingWindowLevel?

Comment: @BUDDAx2 Does the main window have a title bar or a resize bar? If you send `-canBecomeKeyWindow` to the main window, what is the return value?

Comment: -canBecomeKeyWindow returns true

Comment: I understand what I need: [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
But I compiling my apps for 10.6 and 10.5. NSRunningApplication class is only in 10.6.

How to do that in 10.5?

Comment: I don't know why, but [NSApp deactivate]; do what I need :)

Comment: `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; // "Available in OS X v10.0 and later."`

Answer (score 13):

Swift 5 version of @BUDDAx2 answer:

```
NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```