# How can I minimize/maximize windows in macOS with the Cocoa API from a Python script?

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, pyobjc

How can I minimize/maximize windows in **macOS** from a Python script? 
On Windows, there's a win32 api (the `ShowWindow()` function) that can do this. I'd like the macOS equivalent. I'd like to have a script be able to find a window from its title, then  minimize or maximize it.

Is this possible? I assume I need to use the `pyobjc` module for this.

Comment: Try this, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466795/how-to-minimize-a-specific-window-in-python https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385949/python-script-to-minimize-all-but-one-window-kills-panel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are probably different ways to do it, out of which one is by enumerating the running applications and next is enumerating the windows inside the application.

I will show the app approach here

```py
from AppKit import NSApplication, NSApp, NSWorkspace
from Quartz import kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID, CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo

workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
activeApps = workspace.runningApplications()
for app in activeApps:
    if app.isActive():
        options = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly
        windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options,
                                                kCGNullWindowID)
        for window in windowList:
            if window['kCGWindowOwnerName'] == app.localizedName():
                print(window.getKeys_)
                break
        break
```

This will find the current focused app, you can change the logic based on titles or whatever you want

After the `app` is found. You can minimize it using

```py
app.hide()
```

And you can show the app again using

```py
from Cocoa import NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps, NSApplicationActivateAllWindows
app.unhide()
app.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)

# or 
app.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps | NSApplicationActivateAllWindows)
```

Lot of threads I had to refer to get to this solution

[OS X: Move window from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598551/os-x-move-window-from-python)

[How to list all windows from all workspaces in Python on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232433/how-to-list-all-windows-from-all-workspaces-in-python-on-mac)

[How to get Window reference (CGWindow, NSWindow or WindowRef) from CGWindowID in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801195/how-to-get-window-reference-cgwindow-nswindow-or-windowref-from-cgwindowid-in)

["No such file: 'requirements.txt' error" while installing Quartz module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530309/no-such-file-requirements-txt-error-while-installing-quartz-module)

[How to build Apple's Son of grab example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321222/how-to-build-apples-son-of-grab-example)

[How to get another application window's title, position and size in Mac OS without Accessibility API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039717/how-to-get-another-application-windows-title-position-and-size-in-mac-os-witho/3042284#3042284)

[Get the title of the current active Window/Document in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480866/get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-document-in-mac-os-x)

[-[NSRunningApplication activateWithOptions:] not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839290/nsrunningapplication-activatewithoptions-not-working)

[How to start an app in the foreground on Mac OS X with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655484/how-to-start-an-app-in-the-foreground-on-mac-os-x-with-python)

[set NSWindow focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089598/set-nswindow-focused)

[Activate a window using its Window ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152551/activate-a-window-using-its-window-id)

Comment: this doesn't do the minimize animation though is there really not another alternative?