# Is it possible to close a window in macOS with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Actually, I wanna do some automated operations on macOS, like closing a specific window.

I have read some threads, and I got know about `Appkit` and `Quartz` from [How can I minimize/maximize windows in macOS with the Cocoa API from a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237266/how-can-i-minimize-maximize-windows-in-macos-with-the-cocoa-api-from-a-python-sc).

Here below is my current progress:

```
import AppKit

for app in AppKit.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications():
    if app.localizedName() == 'Google Chrome':
        app.hide()
```

With `AppKit`, I can hide a specific application successfully. But there are two issues for me with this method: first, it seems that `AppKit` can only manage **Applications**, but not **Windows** (i.e., the above code hides all *Google Chrome* windows at once); besides, `AppKit` seems to be only able to **Hide** an application, but not **Quitting** it or **Closing** it.

I also tried `Quartz`. With the below code, I can successfully find the specific windows that I wanna control, especially with the characteristic `kCGWindowNumber`. But I would like to ask, is there any module that can allow me to close (or hide) the window, maybe like with the `kCGWindowNumber`?

```
import Quartz

for window in Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, Quartz.kCGNullWindowID):
    if window['kCGWindowOwnerName'] == "Google Chrome" and window['kCGWindowLayer'] == 0:
        print(window)
```

Comment: Probably not the answer you are expecting, but each process on macOS has `PID` you can use `os.kill` to achieve what you want if you know the `PID`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill

Comment: You could try with selenium

Comment: @Gameplay Thanks for your reply. Yes, actually, I only want to close specific windows, and `os.kill` kill the whole process. And different windows of the same application may share the same `PID`, which makes me unable to close a specific window with `os.kill`.

Comment: @Vim Sorry, I didn't make it clear that Google Chrome is just an example. I would also like to close the window of some other applications.